# Checking for a foreign key with lambda expressions before deleting record

Tags: c#, lambda, webforms

I have two tables one called Companies and the other called Locations. Companies has a Id and Name, Locations has Id, CompanyId, Name, and SubAccount. I have two projects. One as IMS.Data where all the validation is and IMS where the webforms pages are. I am having trouble validating that if the company has a location(if the company id is a foreign key anywhere) then do not delete the record. Here is what I have so far and everything works but I can not reference the Locations CompanyId in order to do a check using lambda expressions. can anyone help me I am new to lambda expressions.

Here is the method I am using for the validation

```
    namespace IMS.Data
{
public class CompanyContext : IMSDBContext
{
    public Company DeleteCompany(Company company)
    {
        if (company.Name == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Please select a record to delete.");
        }
        if (Companies.Any(x => x.Name == company.Name))
        {
            throw new Exception("Can not delete a company that has a location.");
        }
        Companies.Remove(company);
        return company;
    }

}
}
```

Here is the the delete button I use

```
namespace IMS
{

public partial class CompanySetUp : Page
{
    private const string AddButton = "Add";
    private const string SaveButton = "Save";
    private const string DeleteButton = "Delete";
    private const string CancelButton = "Cancel";

    private int CompanyId // This puts the "CompanyId" into a viewstate and is used to update the record
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)ViewState["_companyId"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["_companyId"] = value;
        }
    }

    private IList<Company> Companies { get; set; } // This gets and sets the list of companies from the table "Companies"

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateCompanyListGrid();
        //if (Companies != null && Companies.Count > 0) // This will put a record in the "txtCompanyName.Text" on page load
        //{
        //    txtCompanyName.Text = Companies.First().Name;
        //}

    }       

    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // This will delete the record that matches the textbox or throw an exception
    {
        CompanyContext context = null;
        switch (btnDelete.Text)
        {
            case DeleteButton:
                try
                {
                    context = new CompanyContext();
                    var company = context.Companies.ToList().First(x => x.Name == txtCompanyName.Text);

                    context.DeleteCompany(company);
                    //PopulateCompanyListGrid();
                    Reload();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblCompanyNameNotification.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (context != null)
                    {
                        context.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                PopulateCompanyListGrid();
                break;
            case CancelButton:
                Reload();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is very unclear to me `...but I can not reference the Locations CompanyId in order to do a check using lamda expressions...`? How do you want to check them?

Comment: In the validation I wanted to put a check that would see if a company had a location (or if a company "id" is a foreign key "companyid" on any other table) then show error message "This Company has a location associated with it and can not be deleted." because of the way that I have the context and each method set up I can not reference the companyid in the locations table to write a statement like this. Well i am sure there is a way but I am only 1 month into my first programming job and not sure how yet. Does that help you understand what I ment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relational database with this data and foreign keys set up properly, you could commit the change and watch for an `SqlException` with code `547`, which is a foreign-key exception. This is thrown when the data to delete is referenced by other tables.

The advantage of handling it this way around is that the data store enforces itself to be valid, instead of defining checks for all the foreign key relations in your code. If you add new FK's later, they will automaticly be enforced by the database and caught by your code, rather than you having to add new checks to the code itself.

Comment: Ok and can I watch or check for that and throw a specific message that I want rather then the default message? How would I watch for that specifically?

Comment: in your `Try..Catch` simply `Catch (SQLException sqlEx) { If (sqlEx.ErrorCode == 547) .... }`